# sms php script cant understand how make html boxes

Tags: php, html, sms

Example PHP script to send SMS gateway

```
$username = "Your Username";
$password = "Your Password";
$sender = "Your Sender ID";
$baseurl ="http://www.google.net/SMSC/API";
$message = urlencode("Your Message");
$to = "Your Reciepients";
// auth call
$url = "$baseurl/action=compose&username=$username&password=$password&sender=$sender
$to=$to&message=$message";
// do auth call
$response = file($url); //Check API section for details of posible response
```

how i make html boxes for this some one help i know its easy but i am biggner in this please
i mean how make front page from where i put number and send button etc..

Comment: You need to create an html page for it.

Create an html add a form there and add input inside the form for the text boxes.

Comment: can you tell me little bit how ? please

Comment: For html page visit the link : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_editors.asp

For Forms in html, visit the link : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: i know this but i dont now how i link send button with what ? and how only i have this which i post already here

Comment: Send button should be your submit button of the form. The form should be submitted to the php page consisting of the php code given above with a little changes.

The variable $username,$password,$sender, $message, $to should be stored by the strings you gave in your input fields in the form, they can be get by POST or GET.